# How to change password for repository in soruceTree 2.1.0?

Tags: java

i changed the password in sourceTree 1.9,but i don't know how to change password in 2.1. please give me some help.

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Authentication -> Edit

Answer (score 0):

I have succeed, i delete the file which is named "password" in "c:user\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree".
 when you push code in souceTree,it will remind you input password.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the answer provided by achAmháin may not work. In that case, just go to "windows credential manager" then click on "Windows Credentials" and find your account in the list. Press on "Edit" and change your password.